# SQL joins across many tables on postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have a table structure as follows:

```
measurements:

id | Value | sensor_id
```

Now I have another table called sensors where

```
sensors:
id | Name | provider_id
```

Then I have another table called Providers as:

```
providers:
id | Name
```

Now what I want to do is select all the records from the measurements table where the sensor_ID has a particular type (specified by an ID).

So I did something like:

```
select * from measurements, sensors, providers 
JOIN sensors on sensors.id = measurements.sensor_id 
JOIN providers on providers.id  = sensor.provider_id 
where provider.id = 1 LIMIT 100
```

However, this comes back with `There is an entry for table "sensor_measurements", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.` I have tried other kind of variants on this but  could not get it to work.

I am using Postgresql and using the PgAdmin tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  So:

```
select *  -- you should list out the columns you want
from measurements m join
     sensors s
     on s.id = m.sensor_id join
     providers p
     on p.id  = s.provider_id 
where p.id = 1
limit 100
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your FROM clause is wrong.
It should either be:

```
FROM 
     measurements 
     JOIN sensors on sensors.id = measurements.sensor_id 
     JOIN providers on providers.id  = sensor.provider_id
```

or alternatively

```
FROM
     measurements,
     sensors,
     providers
WHERE
     providers.id = 1 and
     sensors.provider_id = providers.id
     measurements.sensor_id = sensors.id
```

You're currently including the 3 tables you want but in addition you're joining in the sensors and providers tables yet again, giving you a total of 5 (as far as I can read it).